# inhiritence with java and Mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Can I have an idea about Mapping using inheritence with Java and MongoDB  ?

```
@Document
public abstract class User {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String email;
    //geters & seters & const
}

@Document
public class Person extends User {
    private String x;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(String email, String x) {
        super(email);
        this.x = x;
}

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {}

public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, Long> {}

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestHeritageApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(TestHeritageApplication.class, args);
    PersonRepository personRepository = ctx.getBean(PersonRepository.class);

    Person p= new Person("h@gmail.com", " test");
    personRepository.save(p);
}
```

And I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '   .  .repository.PersonRepository' available

Comment: Is your PersonRepository class inside the same package or is a subpackage of TestHeritageApplication class?

Comment: Is your PersonRepository annotated with @Repository?